# Network is unreachable when using $HttpSocket to post data

Tags: cakephp

I'm using CakePHPs $HttpSocket to post some JSON between 2 cake applications. This works fine when I use a different testing server (hosted with our hosting provider) but when I add the code to our internal web server, where the app resides, I just get

```
Network is unreachable - Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.
```

That's even with debug turned to 2. I've checked all the settings in phpinfo() for both the working and non working server and they appear to be the same.

Could anyone suggest why $HttpSocket will not work on my intranet server?

Heres my stacktrace:

[image]

Code for skywalker:

```
// Post to API
$HttpSocket = new HttpSocket();
$response = $HttpSocket->post($url, $data);
```

Comment: What is the version of cake you are using? Maybe they use different PHP versions.

Comment: @skywalker cake 2.3.4. Working server uses PHP 5.4.27 non working server uses 5.3.10. Both have near identical settings in phpinfo()

Comment: Can you show your code in `admin_add` action?

Comment: @skywalker I've added the relevant bit, I can add the rest of the controller too if you want but it's not really related

Comment: I had some server errors like that and it was usually something I did. Are both cake apps on the same web server?

Comment: No, at first I have them on 2 external (as in live on the web) servers. One app is staying external (the API) but the other, the app that is having httpsocket issues is now on my internal intranet server. Apart from the PHP versions the settings are almost identical. I wonder if its some server config I'm missing.

Comment: Is there some kind of firewall blocking your internal server from calling out to the real world?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end it turned out to be the configuration of our internal network where the server resides. Outgoing traffic was being dropped when it our firewall. Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

It happens for me when it doesn't have internet connection.  So see if the internet connection is working or not from intranet server.